# How to create lots of SQL-Developer Connections quickly?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I wonder if there is a way to create lots of ***SQL-Developer*** connections in "one shot" ?

> **Eg:** By modifying a config file or password file.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?  There is a parameter that makes each new worksheet a new connection.  But, it isn't fast.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Developer stores its connection information in (on Windows):

```
%HOMEPATH%\Appdata\Roaming\SQL Developer\system18.1.0.095.1630\o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.xml
```

The path obviously changes within different versions because of the version number.

I am not aware of any built-in solution for adding entries except the GUI, but it is not that difficult to copy an existing entry and modify the values. Passwords are stored in a hashed form, copying an existing hash value works as well.